# jquery add class to class and ajax load new content

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

the idea is list and grid classs.
example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cfredcf").on('click', function() {
        $('.course-title-cf').removeClass('cfbluecf-p');
        $('.course-title-cf').addClass('cfredcf-p');

    });

    $(".cfbluecf").on('click', function() {
        $('.course-title-cf').removeClass('cfredcf-p');
        $('.course-title-cf').addClass('cfbluecf-p');
    });
    
});
```

```css
    .cfredcf-p{
        color:red;
    }
    .cfbluecf-p{
        color:blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p  class="cfredcf" style="color:red;">red</p>
<p  class="cfbluecf" style="color:blue;">blue</p>
<hr />
<p class="course-title-cf">Title Example</p>
<p class="course-title-cf">Title Example</p>
<p class="course-title-cf">Title Example</p>
<hr />
```

the code working fine until now but when get more  (Title Example) from the database by ajax and already choose red the new results is not coming with red i must click  on red again !.

the new title or results comming from database:
it will be like that

```
<hr />
<p class="course-title-cf">Title Example</p>
<hr />
```

but not geting withe new add class i must click agin to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it would be more effective to add (AJAX) codes and see the scenarios, but,

A lot of solutions come to mind, but if you ask what is the smartest, fastest and easiest one, I would make a `<div>` element that wraps all these `<p>` elements. And until I color each `<p>`, I would do `<div class = "cfredcf-p / cfbluecf-p">`. Then my css is `.cfredcf-p p {color: red;}` I would rearrange it as.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cfredcf").on('click', function() {
    $('.course-title-cf').removeClass('cfbluecf-p');
    $('.course-title-cf').addClass('cfredcf-p');

  });

  $(".cfbluecf").on('click', function() {
    $('.course-title-cf').removeClass('cfredcf-p');
    $('.course-title-cf').addClass('cfbluecf-p');
  });
  
  
  $("button").on('click', function() {
    $('.course-title-cf').append("<p>Title Example</p>");
  });

});
```

```css
.cfredcf-p p {
  color: red;
}

.cfbluecf-p p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="cfredcf" style="color:red;">red</p>
<p class="cfbluecf" style="color:blue;">blue</p>
<button>Add new</button>
<hr />
<div class="course-title-cf">
  <p>Title Example</p>
  <p>Title Example</p>
  <p>Title Example</p>
</div>
<hr />
```

Thus, every new `<p>` element inserted inside the wrapper element will take the same color.